# Can Dense() and Conv2d() can act as same layer function?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Lets suppose that I have a input layer with shape `(h,w,f) = (1 x 1 x 256 )`

And let me make two sequence

case 1 :

```
input = keras.models.Input((1,1,256))
x = keras.layers.Conv2d(f= 32, k=(1,1),s = 1)(input)
x = keras.layers.ReLU()(x) 
x = keras.layers.Conv2d(f= 256, k=(1,1),s = 1)(x)
```

case 2 :

```
input = keras.models.Input((1,1,256))
x = keras.layers.Flatten()(input)
x = keras.layers.Dense(32)(x)
x = keras.layers.ReLU()(x) 
x = keras.layers.Dense(256)(x)
x = keras.layers.reshape((1,1,256))(x)
```

In these 2 cases are the output `x` is same?

I am making a SE-Net-like attention module but not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and you do not need to apply `Flatten()` and `Reshape()` in code 2. Dense will be applied on the last channel automatically.